# PHP-FPM + Apache2 security

Tags: linux, security, chroot, apache-virtualhost, fpm

My question is almost identical to Luis Machuca's from 2 years ago ([Apache + php-fpm: Proper permissions for per-pool, per-user projects?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607598/apache-php-fpm-proper-permissions-for-per-pool-per-user-projects)), but with some additional conditions.

I have also configured the server (mine is an Ubuntu 22.04 machine) so that it is managed by Apache (v2.4.55) and php7.4-fpm. The current configuration allows every vhosts to be divided into specific php-fpm pools, and each of these pools running with different users.

Everything works fine, but security related only to users to control permissions (or based on open_basedir) cannot stop shell_exec (which I need) from accessing, for example, configuration files inside `/etc`, or doing an `ls -l /var/`.

What I would like, therefore, is a way to prevent a user from being able to go around and view linux's standard folders.

I don't want to get to the point of making calls like:

```
setfacl -Rm u:user_site1:--- /;
setfacl -Rm d:u:user_site1:--- /;
```

and then authorizing each fundamental folder one by one. It seems too messy.

I had therefore thought of using chroot inside each pool, but I was not able to do so because there was always a problem related to paths `AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'`, and all online solutions say to modify the `ProxyPassMatch` call based on port 9000, but I use `SetHandler` with sockets and I don't want to change this setting.

What are the possible techniques? Do I really have to install SELinux?

Below, I am adding my configurations to better understand the situation.

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.site.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    H2Direct on
    ServerAdmin server@site.com
    ServerName www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.site.com/httpdocs
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/www.site.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/www.site.com/log/access.log combined
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-www_site_com.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
        H2Direct on
        ServerAdmin server@site.com
        ServerName www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.site.com/httpdocs
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/www.site.com/log/error_ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/www.site.com/log/access_ssl.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.site.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/www.site.com.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(?:cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-www_site_com.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf`

```
[global]
pid = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid
error_log = "syslog"
syslog.ident = php-fpm
include=/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

`/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www_site_com.conf`

```
[www.site.com]
user = user_site1
group = user_site1
listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm-www_site_com.sock
listen.owner = user_site1
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```